# Log file to view last changes made by puppet agent

Tags: puppet

If you do `puppet agent -t` for when agent runs in background, where is the **log file** where we can see the changes, other than on  puppet dashboard.

I viewed puppet.conf and in main section I see `logdir`, but no log file is created on that location.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631338/how-to-show-a-summary-of-the-last-puppet-agent-run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

> When running as a service, Puppet agent logs messages to syslog. Your
>   syslog configuration dictates where these messages will be saved, but
>   the default location is /var/log/messages on Linux,
>   /var/log/system.log on Mac OS X, and /var/adm/messages on Solaris.
>
> When started with the --logdest FILE option, Puppet agent logs to the file specified by FILE.
>
> https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.8/services_agent_unix.html#running-puppet-agent-as-a-service

As Raul mentions, the last run report is saved as a yaml file under the statedir directory.

Depending on your OS and which version of Puppet your using, this could be in different locations.

For example, on my server with Puppet 4 installed:

```
$ tree $(puppet agent --configprint statedir)
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state
├── classes.txt
├── graphs
│   ├── expanded_relationships.dot
│   ├── relationships.dot
│   └── resources.dot
├── last_run_report.yaml
├── last_run_summary.yaml
├── resources.txt
├── state.yaml
└── transactionstore.yaml

1 directory, 9 files
```

A great tool for reading this last report file is [report-print](https://github.com/ripienaar/puppet-reportprint). If there's a particular piece of information you need out of the last report, you could probably adapt some of the report-print code to make your own report printer.

You can also use what's known as report processor, which is when you write custom code to control the format and process the, such as posting to a Splunk server, Slack, Hipchat etc. A simple example would be [store_json](https://github.com/thrnio/puppet-store_json), which stores the reports as JSON instead of Yaml.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, take a look at system log (`/var/log/messages` or `journalctl`).
You should have a report of each execution, in `.yaml` format inside `/var/lib/puppet`

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but the accepted answer didn't help me so here is an alternative that others may find useful. If your puppet runs occurred a while ago, then its output may not appear in `/var/log/messages`.

Instead, you can view the summary (and report) of the last puppet run on a node in `/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml` (and `last_run_report.yaml`). The report is a full log of the previous run, while the summary is brief overview. They have information that you may not be able to get from `messages`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Puppets logs file path: `C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\cache\state`

Here you will find a few files, the most useful of which I have found to be:
last_run_report.yaml and last_run_summary.yaml

As of now, this path is valid for Puppet versions 6.18^