# Codedeploy + Puppet logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, aws-code-deploy

I am running puppet scripts using AWS codedeploy. When a puppet script fails, I do not have any reference to it. In codedeploy-agent.log I just see success logs.
Is there a way to see the output of the puppet scripts I run through codedeploy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256311/log-file-to-view-last-changes-made-by-puppet-agent

Answer (score 0):

I found that the deployments logs are here:

```
`/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log`
```

Each deployment log is located at:

```
`/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/[deployment-group-ID]/[deployment-ID]/logs/scripts.log`
```