# How to show a summary of the last puppet agent run?

Tags: configuration, config, puppet

As Ubuntu administrator I want to know status of each or last puppet agent run.
How can I check with cli?
Can I write to logs each run in human readable format?

Comment: With a cli: no. There are files on the master that store the last run info and messages on the client has the output, but people generally set up reporters for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

puppet maintain last puppet agent run status in  /var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml. you can refer that yaml file content.
**To know when puppet agent last ran on client server  you can check timestamp** 
of that file via using below command (`stat`) or your preferred any other command.

```sh
stat /var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml
```

Comment: An up-to-date answer would be.  

```cat /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_report.yaml```

Comment: Thanks! As per @16c7x the location has changed a little. The command I ran for my reports is:
stat -c %y /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summary.yaml  | awk '{print $1}'

Answer (score 3):

Davendra's answer is great but the location has since changed. To check the last run time use:

```
stat -c %y /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summary.yaml"
```

For reporting - if you just want the date (and not the time) you can use:

```
stat -c %y /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summary.yaml" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with running a new puppet agent run you can use this CLI command:

```
puppet agent --test --summarize
```

This prints a nice summary at the end of the output of the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a `dry` test. Checkout Puppet `noop` mode mode allows us to review the changes that Puppet would do on the system without actually applying them. This is particularly useful when managing critical servers, as it allows to push to production Puppet code and data in a more controlled, safe and manageable way!!

```
puppet agent -t --noop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
cat /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/last_run_report.yaml
```

use `stat` instead of `cat` and check the timestamp to see when the last run was.

```
/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml
```

is outdated now

hope this helps :)